# How to get a model's last access date in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm building a Django application, and in it I would like to track whenever a particular model was last accessed.

I'm opting for this in order to build a user activity history.

I know Django provides auto_now and auto_now_add, but these do not do what I want them to do. The latter tracks when a model was created, and the former tracks when it was last modified, which is different from when it was last accessed, mind you.

I've tried adding another datetime field to my model's specification:

```
accessed_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then I try to update the model's access manually by calling the following after each access:

```
model.accessed_on = datetime.utcnow()

model.save()
```

But it still won't work.

I've gone through the django documentation for an answer, but couldn't find one.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, after fumbling with the problem a little bit more, I discovered that the reason why my code didn't work was because it wasn't actually being executed in the larger context of the application (I had an erroneous if clause). Still though, Django should really include a last accessed datetime parameter for models. It just makes sense as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I think if you spend some time thinking about this, you'll understand this really isn't something Django should do out of the box.  If you need this, you can implement it.  But unlike the date time fields, which include updates on create/save, this is an action which has multiple different ways to implement based on a variety of needs and infrastructure.  As a result, there's no one good way to cover all requirements, so it really should not be part of the core framework, but available as a third party application.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a model with a field that contains the last save-date. Plus saving the object every time is translated from the DB representation to the python representation?

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    date_accessed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @classmethod
    def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):
        obj = super().from_db(db, field_names, values)
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: Well it's been two years since I had that problem and I just solved it by manually updating it each time, but thanks. This is a much much more elegant solution.